# check availability using php mysql version 5.6.17

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a trouble regarding on checking the room availability.

table roomaguila

---

- room_id : 3
- room_name : aguila2
- room_arrival : 10/04/2016
- availability : Occupied

table booking

---

- bk_id : 3
- bk_room : aguila2
- bk_arrival : 10/04/2016
- bk_departure : 10/09/2016

I need the customer to check the room if it's available or not .for example if the customer enter a room, arrival and departure but he/she enter his/her arrival date and departure is aguila2 10/3/2016 and 10/5/2016 he/she prompted the the room is not available .

currently here's my sample code

```
$room = $_POST['room'];
$arrival = $_POST['arrival'];
$departure = $_POST['departure'];

$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking WHERE bk_room = '$room'
  AND $arrival BETWEEN bk_arrival AND bk_departure;");
```

Comment: So, you are reporting that your code is using the deprecated mysql_ interface functions, and is subject to SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Was there a *question*?

Comment: This is just my sample program but still I just want to know how to manage the check availability so that I can learn from it then I will start to read some tutorials using PDO.

Comment: This is an international site. When you write '10/09/2016', no one has any idea whether you mean the 10th September or the 9th October. MySQL has no idea either, so just stick to dates that are properly formatted (from MySQL's point of view).